# c++ program doesn't run on server

Tags: c++, gcc, windows-server-2008

Situation:

I have a small program which opens and changes xml-files. Afterwards, the xml-files will be saved and then I update and insert some data from the xml-files into a few tables. That's pretty much the whole deal.

Here's the problem:
I want the tool to run once a day on a server with windows task scheduler on windows server 2008 which doesn't work. I start the task and the tool completely freezes. I can't even kill the task neither with task manager nor with "taskkill /f ...".

If I run it on my local machine it works flawless.
The program is written in C++ and compiled with gcc. Following 2 .dlls are needed for the program to work, which I put in the same folder:

```
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
```

Any ideas are well appreciated.

Comment: You should try putting dlls in the PATH.

Comment: try to test you program from command line in the server
or lanch it from a scheduler task in you PC

Answer (score 0):

Not really a direct answer to your problem, but since any idea is appreciated: 
you can try linking statically the C/C++ with `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++`
By doing this, you won t need anymore to carry with you these 2 libraries